# Label text will not change before database connection

Tags: c#, user-interface, label

What I am trying to do is to display 'Please wait.." in the place of a value that will be fetched and displayed on the form using the connection with a remote database. In this process I wrote a simple code as follows:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             c.Text = "Please wait...";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
.
.
.
.
}
```

I debugged the code and found out that the line changing `c.Text` is executed but somehow the form is frozen and it only changes once the connection is established, query is run and data is fetched.

I understand that since i am not using threading the UI will get stuck, but despite that what causes the label not to change right before its stuck?

Comment: Have you tried MyForm.Refresh() after setting the text?

Comment: The UI Thread is the only thread that can update the visuals. But the UI thread is currently busy doing your "button_click" code. So you do set the text value of the textbox, but the UI thread doesn't update the screen untill it's done with your code.

Comment: most of win applications are single thread applications, by default.
what you can do here, use jquery for web applications or, async programming for all .net appliations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add

```
this.Refresh();
```

after you set the text, it invalidates the forms and updates it.

Answer (score 2):

The `c.Text` assignment will set the text, but the repaint messages are handeled after the onclick handler finishes.

Try this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         c.Text = "Please wait...";
         Application.DoEvents();
         SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
```

But I must say, it's bad habbit to perform blocking operations in the UI thread. (because with this you request to handle events from a eventhandler)

Especially in this case: because this pattern can cause infinite loops or dead-locks.

It is better to perform the database operation on a workerthread or using the `async` and `await` patterns of .NET 4.5

Comment: i believe this style will left user in deep trouble at some moment.

Comment: @Arun: yes, it would be better to put the whole database operation on a workerthread or use the `async` - `await` pattern.

Comment: Yes, I understand the risk in not using workerthread, however, it is a very simple application and serves a single purpose. In the later stages, I will have to integrate another small application with it and it will be then when i would restructure the app, meanwhile I feel I can afford to be lazy for a week.

Comment: Going async just adds *one* line of code ^^ :
await Task.Run(()=>{/* YOUR CODE */});